# Select options appear displaced

Tags: javascript, html, select

Our application shows some select displaced in chrome

Options are displaced to left.

[image]

This happen when using multiple screen. Resizing screen fixe this issue.

We don't have custom css on options

[image: css]

Any idea how we can fix it.

UPDATED 1:

CSS select

[image]

Comment: Those screenshots given are too small and not clear. Please update your question with better screenshots.

Comment: I have just updated the screenshots.

Comment: What is the styling for the select element? Also, what media queries are you using to alter the layout.

Comment: Please describe how to reproduce this behavior (environment, screen resolution, container size etc).

Comment: Chrome 76. Portable pc with two screens, each 1080x1920 native. Text 100% as recomended. No chrome extension.

Comment: just a wild guess, but have you tried to remove the 115% Width ? Also the Font can be the problem

Comment: Finally, in the main screen, windows text font was set to 125%. Changing to 100% was seen correctly on each screen

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use the padding property, your elements can go outside the div.
Force them to stay inside by using `box-sizing: border-box;`
This will maybe help you.